# django send file after a process is done

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a function `foo` on an uploaded file then send the output file to the user, I have written a functions to store the uploaded file and send emails (both works),I need help in attaching the output file once the function is completed `foo()` which takes about 1-2 hours to complete. 
this is my `views.py`

```
import time
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def My_Upload(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        name = fs.save(name=uploaded_file.name,content=uploaded_file)
        context = {'Name':name}
        #function
        return render(request,'my_app/homepage.html',context=context)
    return render(request,'my_app/upload.html',)

def send_email_to(filename=None):
    foo(filename)
    send_mail("Your file is ready", "Here is your file", 'example@gmail.com', 
        ['1234@gmail.com'],fail_silently=False)

def foo(filename):
    #run some math on the file
    #creates a f'{filename}_done.csv'
    time.sleep(300)
    pass
```

is there a way to do this, if not what alternatives do I have for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more complete answer in your project folder,add a new file celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','Proj.settings')
app = Celery('Proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

in Proj init.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

This is just default setup for any celery App, for your case
in your app create a new file tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
import time
from django.core.mail import send_mail
@shared_task
def sent_email_to():
    time.sleep(10)
    send_mail("Your file is ready", "Here is your file", '123@gmail.com', 
        ['example@gmail.com'],fail_silently=False)
return None
```

then in your views.py

```
from .tasks import sent_email_to

def My_Upload(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        name = fs.save(name=uploaded_file.name,content=uploaded_file)
        context = {'Name':name}
        sent_email_to()
        return render(request,'my_app/homepage.html',context=context)
    return render(request,'my_app/upload.html',)
```

finally in the settings.py you need to add

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'CELERY_SERVER_URL'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

run the celery server using

```
celery -A Proj -l info
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is taking too long you said 1-2 hours, you can make a **baground task** of it using **celery** and call `send_email_to` in that task itself. For attaching file you can look at [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)

You can refer [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) here, add call `send_mail_to` as **delay** function(run in baground) in your My_Upload function.

It should look something like:

```
import time
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from proj.celery import app

def My_Upload(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        name = fs.save(name=uploaded_file.name,content=uploaded_file)
        context = {'Name':name}
        send_mail_to.delay()
        return render(request,'my_app/homepage.html',context=context)
    return render(request,'my_app/upload.html',)

@app.task
def send_email_to(filename=None):
    foo(filename)
    send_mail("Your file is ready", "Here is your file", 'example@gmail.com', 
        ['1234@gmail.com'],fail_silently=False)

def foo(filename):
    #run some math on the file
    #creates a f'{filename}_done.csv'
    time.sleep(300)
    pass
```

P.S: **proj** is your django-project name

Comment: can you provide more details on how that would go?